# Is it possible to download and run code on iOS

Tags: ios, enterprise

I realize this isn't permitted in the App Store but I'd like to do this for an Enterprise app. I'm looking to download some compiled code (a static lib perhaps) and run from it.

In case someone's interested, I'm trying to do this to workaround the fact that I can't upgrade and enterprise app on a Single App Mode in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you tried this out and it didn't fit your needs:

[Apple Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

There are a few others ways to run custom code on an iPhone.  Starting with the official and working toward the grey:

1) If you buy a standard developer license you can load compiled code onto your iphone

2) If your developer is legit, they can send you to a limited use beta (recently the folks at Lift did this with their beta)

3) Javascript is code: webapps count.

4) Of course, Jailbreaking is an option, but for your enterprise app this might not be feasible.

I'm guessing the top link is best.

Comment: I am part of the iOS Enterprise program and I have an app that I've written ... I just want it to be able to download a static library and run it (like point the PC to it and let it go).